# Obvious to anyone but me Angular component receives data but does not update

Tags: angular

I have an intro page which fetches terms of service via a GET REST call. The call works, however, it always results in one or more 304's and a 200. The data exists though. Every console.log prints values. The variable `terms` gets defined in the complete call. The initial, hey I got data, lambda might be storing the value, but Angular doesn't care and ignores it. I only have this problem in this code. Not sure how this is different.

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TermsService } from '../../core/services/terms.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-terms',
    templateUrl: './terms.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./terms.component.css']
})
export class TermsComponent implements OnInit {
    terms: string;
    constructor(private termsService: TermsService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.termsService.getProperties().subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => { 
    console.log('received data='+data);
                this.terms = data['terms'];
            },(error)=> {
                console.log('Error getting terms'+error);
            },() => {
                console.log('Completed terms call');
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay-fullscreen" id="termsDialog" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" data-close-button="false">
    <div class="overlay-box ds-col-md-12" role="document">
      <div class="row ds-padding-bottom-0_5 ds-align-text-left ds-mar-t-2 ds-mar-b-5">
        <div class="ds-col-md-12">
          <div class="row ds-overlay-content">
            <div class="row overlay-content ds-offset-xs-1 ds-col-md-10">
              <h2 class="ds-heading-2 ds-pad-1 ds-pad-r-2">Terms & Conditions</h2>
              <p id="textTerms" class="terms-cond" >
                 {{ terms }}    
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row overlay-content">
            <div class="ds-col-xs-12 ds-col-md-7 ds-col-lg-4 ds-offset-4 ds-col-lg-5">
              <button class="ds-close-focused ds-button" id="termsDialogCloseBtn">ACCEPT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: data is an object or an array? you has `subscribe((data: any[])=>{...}` if is an array sure **is wrong** `this.terms=data['terms']` if is an object should be `subscribe((data:any)=>{...}` -btw with object you can use `data.terms`-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted all the previous replies because it was part of solution. But the real problem I had was the data was of type anytype, but effectively a string. When I did JSON.parse(data), I was able to extract the term.

I know people absolutely love Node and Typescript, but if there were real type checking, I would not have been able to request a property of an object of type any.

Answer (score 1):

You should put an `*ngIf` when you're fetching data, because at first it is not defined.

```html
<p *ngIf="terms" id="textTerms" class="terms-cond" >
  {{ terms }}    
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` in view that can handle the data binding of terms.
Or you can declare the term as an empty string. like

```
terms: string = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you should put an *ngIf when you're fetching data as initially **terms** is not defined. I've updated and attached your code below.

```
<div class="overlay-container">
      <div class="overlay-fullscreen" id="termsDialog" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" data-close-button="false">
        <div class="overlay-box ds-col-md-12" role="document">
          <div class="row ds-padding-bottom-0_5 ds-align-text-left ds-mar-t-2 ds-mar-b-5">
            <div class="ds-col-md-12">
              <div class="row ds-overlay-content">
                <div class="row overlay-content ds-offset-xs-1 ds-col-md-10">
                  <h2 class="ds-heading-2 ds-pad-1 ds-pad-r-2">Terms & Conditions</h2>
                  <p *ngIf="terms" id="textTerms" class="terms-cond" >
                     {{ terms }}    
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row overlay-content">
                <div class="ds-col-xs-12 ds-col-md-7 ds-col-lg-4 ds-offset-4 ds-col-lg-5">
                  <button class="ds-close-focused ds-button" id="termsDialogCloseBtn">ACCEPT</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```